# Organizing inherited services in webapi controller

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My problem is this:

1. I need to call two different services with similar API through HTTP.
   Let's say I derived IBaseService with two methods - MakeOrder and CancelOrder.
2. Service I want to call is determined by request I receive - It contains serviceToCall attribute.
3. I use Asp.NET core basic dependency container and want to have a nice code - some workaround is easy though.

The thing is that I got lost in all the patterns and approaches I can choose (besides DI Factory method or Strategy came to my mind).

Could you guys give me a hint how to solve the issue? I bet there is a way how to do it without if statement in every method.

Comment: You named the two prominently used ones in such a case. Or use a 3rd party IoC container, which support named services

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please improve by showing relevant code that shows what you want to achieve. Show the relevant interfaces. Show the consumers using those interfaces and their interaction. Describe the difference between the two services. Show whether they have the exact same interface or each a different interface. If they have the same interface, explain why they require the same interface and explain why you are not violating [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Explain on which conditions (if any) the application should decide which impl. to use.